# MvxSimpleIoCContainer and multiple concrete implementations

Tags: mvvmcross

If I have interface `IMvxScreen` and multiple concrete classes that implement `IMvxScreen`, is it possible to resolve all implementations at once?

```
public MyClass(IScreen[] screens) 
  {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - this isn't currently possible.

You would have to provide a separate interface/object - e.g. an `IScreenService`.

Assuming all your screens are in the same Assembly, I guess you could provide this using a service like:

```
 public interface IScreenService
 {
     IEnumerable<IScreen> CreateAll();
 }

 public class ScreenService : IScreenService
 {
     public IEnumerable<IScreen> CreateAll()
     {
         return this.GetType().Assembly
                            .CreatableTypes()
                            .Inherits<IScreen>()
                            .Select(t => Mvx.IocConstruct(t));
     }
 }
```